# Sublime Text hour counter plugin

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

Is there any plugin for Sublime Text to count how long i have been working on a project?

It could be a great idea to track the time spent on a specific project, also to get an accurate idea also how many hours to bill clients for freelance projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you search the Package Control website for [`time`](https://sublime.wbond.net/search/time), several relevant options come up near the top:

- [`WakaTime`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/WakaTime) (ST2/ST3) - "fully automatic time tracking for Sublime Text 2 & 3"
- [`Task Timer`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Task%20Timer) (ST2 only) - "A simple task timer for Sublime Text Editor"
- [`Tau Time Tracker`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Tau%20Time%20Tracker) (ST2 only) - "A simple time tracking plugin for Sublime Text 2"

I haven't used any of them, so I can't make a personal recommendation, but just by glancing at the READMEs the WakaTime one looks like it has the most features. YMMV.

Comment: Thanks! Used WakaTime, i get a weekly report divided per project. Highly recommended

Answer (score 1):

To get a full overview on how long you've been doing different things in Sublime Text I can also recommend [codeivate.com](http://codeivate.com/).

This one is not exactly project-based timing but sums up the time that you spent coding different languages and gives a weekly overview on it.
It will certainly not help billing your clients but can be interesting to track your overall work.
Additionally, it's quite fun to compare yourself to others using the same plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. personally it's no use for me if i can't divide by project

Comment: for dividing by project, check out https://wakatime.com which does that automatically